# Accessing an object in JavaScript with argument of function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to make a sort of "shopping list" in JS. I'm having trouble accessing the object with the argument of a function.

```js
shopList = {
  create: function createList(listName) {
    listName = {};
    listName["Banana"] = 2
  },

  output: function output(listName) {
    console.log(listName)
  },

};

shopList.create('list')
shopList.output('list')
```

When I run shopList.output 'list' is returned. How do I access the object over the argument? Hope this isn't a duplicate, been googling for hours now and didn't make any progress.

Comment: 'over the argument'?

Comment: Sorry english isn't my mother tongue. Like access it with the passed arguement.

Comment: It might be better with an example output of what you want.

Comment: I just want to return the entire object in the terminal, so in this case 'banana: 2' should be returned

Comment: `var shopList = {
    create: function createList(listName) {
        this.listName = {};
        this.listName["Banana"] = 2
    },

    output: function output(listName) {
        console.log(this.listName)
    },
};

shopList.create('list');
shopList.output('list');`

Comment: @Tushar Note that [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) won't make use of the variable. It only uses the name of the identifier that follows it, so that property will always be `"listName"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be able to configure lists with dynamic names then you need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to create lists within `this` object. Like this:

```js
var shopList = {
    create: function createList(listName) {
        this[listName] = {};
        this[listName]["Banana"] = 2
    },

    output: function output(listName) {
        return this[listName];
    }
};

shopList.create('list');
console.log(shopList.output('list'));
```

However, as pointed by @armchairdj in comments, it's better to create a container dedicated property to hold lists:

```
var shopList = {
    lists: {},

    create: function createList(listName) {
        this.lists[listName] = {};
        this.lists[listName]["Banana"] = 2
    },

    output: function output(listName) {
        return this.lists[listName];
    }
};
```

Comment: The 2nd `console.log()` isn't necessary since `output()` already logs it rather than `return`ing.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I think it makes sense to return, so not it does :)

Comment: That's a little naive. `shopList.create('output')` would break your object.

Comment: @armchairdj I know, it's just OP's is creating very simple shopping cart. But you are right.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid clobbering the methods of your showList object by naively adding arbitrary, user-supplied keys, you should create an internal namespace for your lists.

```js
var shopList = {
  lists:  {},

  create: function (listName) {
    this.lists[listName] = this.lists[listName] || {};

    this.lists[listName].Banana = 2;
  },

  output: function (listName) {
    var list = this.lists[listName];

    if (!list) {
      return console.log('No list named ' + listName + ' found.');
    }

    console.log(list)
  }
};

shopList.create('output');
shopList.output('output');
shopList.create('foo');
shopList.output('foo');
shopList.output('bar');
```